# primary constructor, values with underscore

Tags: scala, scala-primary-constructor

A try this (in Scala 2.10.3) :

```
scala> class A(var a: Int = _)
<console>:1: error: unbound placeholder parameter
       class A(var a: Int = _)
                            ^
```

What is the problem?, the underscore for default value-type can not be used in a primary constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underscore is used for placeholder of the default value of the type (see Scala language specification). I am not really sure why you would want to do this type of initialization instead of: `class A(var a: Int = 0)` as it is likely to be more concise and other coders will know immediately the default value.

Comment: Only testing for study the language, my question is, if a try this: scala> class A { var a: Int = _ }
defined class A, then there is no problem with it, because the value of a constructor is a field for the class or not?.

Comment: When using curly braces, you're defining the body of the class. With `{ var a: Int _ }` you've created an instance variable, `a` which is initialized to the default value of `Int`. When doing `class A(var a: Int = _)` you're asking scala to create an new class `A` which accepts an `Int` in it's constructor argument.

Comment: Ok, I thought the value in a constructor was created like a field so this would allow use underscore for default value :( , Thanks for you time.

Comment: You are correct, scala will provide a getter/setter for that field. For instance, `class A(val myInt: Int)` can later be accessed externally via: `val a = new A(4); println(a.myInt)`. Without the val/var in the constructor argument that parameter will not be a field of the class.

Comment: Seems inconsistent that Scala programmers should only sometimes use "_" to represent the default value of a type. Anybody know why Scala language designers decided to do it this way?